# Invoking a service from runnable calls previous action before new action. How to prevent this?

Tags: android, service, runnable

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    long i = 0;
    final String TAG="MyService";
    public void onCreate() {
        //initialize service here
    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        log.i(TAG, i+":BEGIN");
        if (intent!=null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            log.i(TAG, i+":"+action);
            if (action.equals("RETRIEVE_SETTINGS_FROM_NET_SERVER") {
                new GetSettings().run();
            } else if (action.equals("RESTART_SERVICE_COMPONENT")) {
                //create alarmmanager code here
            }
            log.i(TAG, i+":complete");
            i++;
        }
    }
    private class GetSettings implements Runnable {
        String urlString;
        public GetSettings(String _urlString) {
            if (_urlString!=null) urlString = _urlString;
        }
        public void run() {
            HttpURLConnection c;
            if (urlString!= null) {
                try {
                    URL u = new URL(urlString);
                    c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();
                    int serverResponse = c.getResponseCode();
                    switch (serverResponse) {
                        case HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK:
                            InputStream in;
                            in = c.getInputStream();
                            int next = -1;
                            StringBuffer tmpSvrResp = new StringBuffer();
                            while ((next = in.read()) != -1) {
                                tmpSvrResp.append((char)next);
                            }
                            in.close();
                            Map <String, String> newSettings = splitQuery(tmpSvrResp.toString());
                            //Apply new settings.
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    log.i(e.toString());
                } finally {
                    if (c!=null) c.disconnect();
                    if (isSuccessful)
                        Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, MyService.class);
                        i.setAction("RESTART_SERVICE_COMPONENT");
                        startService(i); //This call repeats RETRIEVE SETTINGS... action
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Error: setting new configuration from server!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private Map<String, String> splitQuery(URL url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Map<String, String> query_pairs = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        String query = url.getQuery();
        String[] pairs = query.split("&");
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
            query_pairs.put(URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8"), URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8"));
        }
        return query_pairs;
    }
}
here is a sample log...

MyService    0:BEGIN
MyService    0:RETRIEVE_SETTINGS_FROM_NET_SERVER
MyService    0:complete
MyService    1:BEGIN
MyService    1:RETRIEVE_SETTINGS_FROM_NET_SERVER
MyService    1:complete
MyService    2:BEGIN
MyService    2:RESTART_SERVICE_COMPONENT
MyService    2:complete
```

Hi, I searched but I cannot find anything similar. I have a service that gets updated settings from a server. Then I restart the schedule. My problem is whenever I call the startservice(i); The service will call the intent with the previous action first before running the new action.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied and executed your code, and its working fine for me.
I only added `return START_NOT_STICKY;` at the end of `onStartCommand()`. And here is my log:

```
08-01 11:09:33.840: I/MyService(1333): 0:BEGIN
08-01 11:09:33.840: I/MyService(1333): 0:RETRIEVE_SETTINGS_FROM_NET_SERVER
08-01 11:09:33.861: I/MyService(1333): 0:complete
08-01 11:09:34.051: I/MyService(1333): 1:BEGIN
08-01 11:09:34.051: I/MyService(1333): 1:RESTART_SERVICE_COMPONENT
08-01 11:09:34.051: I/MyService(1333): 1:complete
```

I guess you're doing something wrong in the code that you have hide from us. like here:

```
//create alarmmanager code here
```

or here:

```
//retrieve settings from internet server here...
//parse values
//apply new service scheduled interval
```

Please check yourself, or show us the code so that we can see where's the problem.

Also show us the code from where you are setting Intent's action and starting this Service for first time.

Comment: I'll try the START_NOT_STICKY. Thanks for the suggest. I'll edit the code later :D

Comment: I looked into your edited code, but could not find anything. It should work fine. By the way, is that the complete log that you've shared? Also please check if you have not called `startIntent(i)` two times at the place from where you are starting the intent for first time.

Comment: I found the mistake. I have a broadcast receiver that starts the intent as well and there was double startService(i) there. One was the original startService(i);followed by a context.startService(i);

Comment: I thought it was so :) That is why I was insisting you to show us the code where you was starting the service. Anyways.. glad that you could fix it.